# I am getting an error that reads “The given path's format is not supported.” when trying to upload audio file to sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, file-upload

I am able to upload other file types to share point using the lines of code below. However, when I try to upload an uadio file I get an error that reads  "The given path's format is not supported" on the line where it trys to create the directory and save the file on SharePoint.  The line reads `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);`

I am suspecting the backslashes in path below my be a problem

**Path**

```
public static string CMSdocs1drive = "\\\\myserver.sharepoint.com@SSL\\DavWWWRoot\\personal\\myname_myorganisation_org_com\\";
```

**Code To Upload And Save To SharePoint**

```
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            if (FileUpload_Section55_6.HasFile)
                {

                    if (ddlDocument.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + "Upload status: Please select the document type." + "');", true);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            if (FileUpload_Section55_6.PostedFile.ContentLength < 2014572800)
                            {
                                {


                                    if (ddlFilingType.SelectedIndex != 0)
                                    {
                                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblCaseID0.Text) && ddlDocument.SelectedValue.ToString() == "203")
                                            pathString = CMSProperties.CMSdocs1drive + "\\" + lblCaseID0.Text + "\\" + ddlFilingType.SelectedItem.Text + "\\" + ".Mp3";
                                    }

                                    if (!Directory.Exists(pathString))
                                    {

                                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
                                        // System.IO.Directory.Move(pathString);

                                    }
                                    if (pathString != controller.CheckIfFilePathExist(pathString))
                                    {

                                        controller.UploadFile(pathString, lblCaseID.Text);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + "Upload status: The file is to big!" + "');", true);
                            }
                            ddlDocument.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ex.Message.ToString();
                            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured:" + "');" + ex, true);
                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }


                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + "Upload status: Please select file  " + "');", true);
                }
        }
```

Comment: @mjwills please note the line of code that first attempts to create the directory. I strong suspect that it is failing to even create the directory possibly because of the baclslashes or something else to do with the way something in the path is formatted

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of a command prompt with that folder or one of its parents as the current directory?

Answer (score 0):

> I am suspecting the backslashes in path below my be a problem

Consider using a [Verbatim Operator( @ )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#regular-and-verbatim-string-literals) for the path to denote that it contains escape sequence characters (the `\` symbol) that should be ignored.

> ```cs
> public static string CMSdocs1drive = "\\\\myserver.sharepoint.com@SSL\\DavWWWRoot\\personal\\myname_myorganisation_org_com\\";
> ```

with the verbatim operator you can avoid the use of additional escape sequence characters, for example:

```cs
     public static string CMSdocs1drive = @"\\myserver.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\personal\myname_myorganisation_org_com\";
```

Comment: You changed the second character of the string.